# Is a classical (chaotic) double pendulum actually in a quantum superposition when not observed after some time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Inspired by [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/658544/is-there-a-relationship-between-quantum-physics-and-chaos-theory-on-a-classical), I wonder if classical (chaotic) double pendulums are actually in a quantum superposition when not observed.

Chaotic physical systems are systems where slightly different initial positions eventually produce substantially different outcomes after some time.

For example, after enough time, even the smallest differences of starting positions of a double-pendulum will end up producing very different outcomes. Now (loosely speaking) even a massive system will have some quantum uncertainty to its center-of-mass position (yes, a pendulum really is a more complicated system but I suspect there is some level of truth to this...there surely is some quantum uncertainty to a massive quantum system's center-of-mass, right?). So, a massive system is therefore in a superposition of different tiny changes in positions (as long as these tiny positions are not "measured").

If you consider the classical evolution of each of these superpositions (of tiny changes in position of the massive quantum system) - they evolve chaotically, and eventually there will be a time when the outcomes are completely different. Yet, if the pendulum is completely isolated - wouldn't it remain in a superposition until measured? This would suggest that you could have "Schrodinger's Pendulums" where the macroscopic outcome is substantially different upon measurement.

Is there any sense to this idea? I suspect the responses will insist that decoherence ruins the fun, but I don't exactly get the intuition for why this can be argued for in general. If you think of a pendulum as a gigantic mass of particles all with harmonic oscillator potentials all connected to their nearest neighbor - then how does this system's positional uncertainty decohere without being explicitly measured by an observer?

Comment: As you suggested, this is like Schrödinger's cat (but your version is better, because it's more civilized). The same concepts apply in both cases. If you're not so sure that the same concepts apply in both cases, then can you clarify what you think is the key difference?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly, uh, well in the case of Schrodinger's cat there are some arguments that you're not really going to be able to prepare a superposition because of "decoherence." I've never quite understood the precise argument there - but thinking about it more - I think you're probably right that it might just be the exact same thing. Although this does seem to suggest that probably most classical systems (when not observed) are actually in quantum superpositions until you measure them (since most things in nature some some degree of butterfly effect).

Comment: I don't think the argument is precise, which might explain why you don't feel like you've understood it. :) Decoherence doesn't prevent such superpositions on paper, it just prevents any feasible measurement from revealing the existence of such a superposition -- which is the same as saying that we can't prepare such a superposition in the lab in any feasibly-verifiable way. So whether or not such superpositions exist physically might be untestable, which might make your question kind of hard to answer definitively.

Comment: With Schrödingers Cat there are only two states because the radioactive atom is in a superposition of two states. With the double pendulum there were infinitely many states in superposition (if the answer to your question is yes). Great question but I have no clue how to tackle it. I think that for an idealised pendulum (two point masses, constraints for their distance, gravitational potential) it is maybe not even too difficult to write down the Schrödinger Equation.

Comment: I come from the other question and I am finding [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0605249) interesting (it deals with a chaotic asteroid instead of a double pendulum, however). Maybe it helps to understand the role of decoherence a bit more.

Comment: Consider a photon in a Gaussian beam. In the focus of the beam the position of the photon is relatively sharp (≙ initial state of the double pendulum), but as the beam spreads out its position becomes blurred (≙ double pendulum evolving in time). If you know the parameters of the Gaussian beam, you can place a lens and refocus it, so the photon's position becomes sharp again. If you don't know the Gaussian beam, randomly placing the lens could redirect the photon anywhere. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) I wonder if there is an analog of the lens for the case of the double pendulum, which brings its state back to a narrow distribution, if you know its state relatively well some time ago.
I'm basically trying to make a connection to the difference between a coherent superposition and a statistical mixture.

Comment: @A.P., I think your question can be rephrased to:  we know classically that after some amount of time the state becomes undeterminable due to not knowing our initial conditions. Quantum mechanically though, we know that this uncertainty in initial conditions is actually due to a true quantum superposition. Therefore this underterminable domain is actually in superposition. And (now your point), since it's in a superposition, in principle there should be some operation that can be done to unitarily bring it back to its initial condition (complete certainty).

Comment: @A.P.,  but yes, not sure what that operator would correspond to, but do also suspect (which I think you do to) that coherent states will pop up in some form since they are the classical characterization of quantum effects.  Probably a quantum treatment to get a classical double pendulum (in the average effect with a tiny quantum standard deviation) would be the way to go and would probably would involve coherent states interacting with eachother.